# Ajax Modal Popup Extender Mark Up on Child Page

Tags: c#, ajax, webforms, parent-child, modalpopupextender

I've been researching for hours a demo of the AJAX Modal Popup Extender markup in a child page.
I'm trying to implement an ASP.NET LinkButton on the parent page in a Gridview column to fire the modal (the child page) and keep the UI markup separate.

Can someone please provide a code demo of this?

Answer (score 0):

Put iframe inside panel and set  src to your file:

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="PanelX" TargetControlID="YourButtonID"
CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="Background">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">
    <iframe   style=" width: 410px; height: 190px;" src="YourChildPage.aspx" runat="server"></iframe>
<br/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none"/>
</asp:Panel>
```